# Populate Pandas dataframe with random sample from another dataframe if condition is met, when columns to be assigned are not independent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, pandas-groupby

I have two DataFrames, `df1` and `df2`. The information in `df1` has to be used to populate cells in `df2` if a specific condition is met. This is an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],"B":[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],"C":[5, 3, 2,10,11,12, 4, 5, 7, 2, 7], "D":[0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[5, 5, 6, 6, 6], "B":[1, 2, 1, 2, 3], "C":np.nan, "D":np.nan})
```

The `np.nan` entries in `df2` are meant to represent the cells that need to be populated. These are empty at the start of the process.

To populate `df2`, I need to use the values in the column `df2['B']`. Specifically, in this example, if the value of `df2['B']` is equal to 1, then I need to get a random sample, with replacement, from `df1[df1['B']==1]`, for both `df1['C']` and `df1['D']`. Importantly, these values are not independent. Therefore, I need to draw a random row from the subset of rows of `df1` where `df1['B']` is equal to one.  And then I need to do this for all rows in `df2`.

Doing `df1[df1['B']==1][['C','D']].sample(replace = True)` draws a random sample for one case when the value of `df1['B']` is one, but

1. How do I assign the corresponding values to `df2`?
2. How do I do this for every row in `df2`?

I have tried several alternatives with loops, such as

```
for index, value in df2.iterrows():
    if df2.loc[index,'B'] == 1:
        temp_df = df1[df1['B'] == 1][['C','D']].sample(n = 1, replace = True)

    if df2.loc[index,'B'] == 2:
        temp_df = df1[df1['B'] == 2][['C','D']].sample(n = 1, replace = True)
        
    if df2.loc[index,'B'] == 3:
        temp_df = df1[df1['B'] == 3][['C','D']].sample(n = 1, replace = True)
        
    if df2.loc[index,'B'] == 4:
        temp_df = df1[df1['B'] == 4][['C','D']].sample(n = 1, replace = True)
        
        
    df2.loc[index, 'C'] = temp_df['C']
    df2.loc[index, 'D'] = temp_df['D']
```

but I get an error message saying

```
---> 15     df2.loc[index, 'C'] = temp_df['C']
     16     df2.loc[index, 'D'] = temp_df['D']
...
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

where the ... denotes lines from the error message that I skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

(i) get the sample sizes from `df2` with `groupby` + `size`.

(ii) use `groupby` + `apply` where we use a lambda function to sample items from `df1` with the sample sizes obtained from (i) for each unique "B".

(iii) assign these sampled values to `df2` (since "B" is not unique, we sorted `df2` by "B" to make the rows align)

```
cols = ['C','D']
sample_sizes = df2.groupby('B')[cols].size()

df2 = df2.sort_values(by='B')
df2[cols] = (df1[df1['B'].isin(sample_sizes.index)]
             .groupby('B')[cols]
             .apply(lambda g: g.sample(sample_sizes[g.name], replace=True))
             .droplevel(1).reset_index(drop=True))
df2 = df2.sort_index()
```

One sample:

```
   A  B   C    D
0  5  1   5  0.6
1  5  2  10  0.7
2  6  1  12  0.6
3  6  2  11  0.5
4  6  3   4  0.1
```